# Mongo query nested json

Tags: mongodb

How to query this kind of structure, it has nested json which don't contain name in Data so there is no keys to get it:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57446f59b9bbb6671ee1a706"),

"item" : "item",

"item2" : "item",

"Data" : [ 
    {
        "Myitem1" : "56",
        "Myitem2" : "45",
    }, 
    {
        "Myitem1" : "21",
        "Myitem2" : "12",
    }, 
    {
        "Myitem1" : "19",
        "Myitem2" : "34",

    }
]
}
```

Comment: what query you want to do?

Comment: i want the value of Myitem1